# Never-ending quicksort

Tags: c, infinite-loop, quicksort, gcc4.9

I tried to implement a quicksort on arrays of `int64_t` like this:

```
void quicksort (int64_t *array,size_t size) { 
    int64_t *split;
    size_t i=0;
    size_t j=size-1;
    if (size>1) {
    split=({
      int64_t p=array[0];
      do {
           for (;array[i]<p;i++);
           for (;array[j]>p;j--);
           swap(array[i],array[j]);
      } while (i<j);
      swap(array[i],array[j]);
      swap(array[j],array[size]);
      &(array[j]);
      })-1;
    quicksort(array,j-1);
    quicksort(split+1,size-j);
    }
    return; 
}
```

Which is good, however, it enters into infinite recursion or infinite loop immediately after first partitioning pass. How can I solve this?

Comment: swap is defined as a macro: `#define swap(a,b) ({               \
typeof(a) __c=(a);                 \
a=b;                               \
b=__c;                             \
})`

Comment: "*How can I solve this?*" compile with symbols (option `-g` for gcc) and run the code in a debugger (gdb for gcc), which allows you to trace it step by step and inspect all relevant variables.

Comment: 0) when [5,5,5] _infinite loop_ at do-while. 1) `array[size]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partitioning code looks weird and there's at least a few things wrong with it:
for (; a[i] < p; i++) is not guaranteed to terminate.

And then if j is the final position of pivot element, your left array should be sorted by quicksort(array, j) and not j-1.

Comment: I'm not sure that solves it, because OP uses `swap(array[j],array[size]);` not `swap(array[j],array[size-1]);`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your code to compile (my compiler is old).  But shouldn't:

```
size_t i=0;
```

be instead initialized as 1 because you have

```
int64_t p=array[0];  // partition element?
```

and

```
for (;array[i]<p;i++);
```

That is probably not the only problem.